# C# - Send e-mail without having to login to server

Tags: c#, smtp, email

I have an application that needs to send e-mails.  Currently, this is what I am using:

```
        System.Net.Mail.MailMessage MyMailMessage = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
        MyMailMessage.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(fromemail.Text);
        MyMailMessage.To.Add(toemail.Text);
        MyMailMessage.Subject = subject.Text;
        MyMailMessage.Body = body.Text;
        System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient SMTPServer = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
        SMTPServer.Port = 587;
        SMTPServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("email", "password");
        SMTPServer.EnableSsl = true;
        SMTPServer.Send(MyMailMessage);
```

Is there a simple way to send an e-mail without having to login to a server?  Thank you.

Comment: I am curious why you need this? Is it because you don't want to have to configure settings inside your app? or expose u/p to users?

Comment: Not sure what "u/p" means.  It's an SMS application that sends messages to cell phones.  It uses the carrier's e-mail extension.  So it's being sent just like a standard e-mail.

Comment: u/p -> username/password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an SMTP server that does not require authentication, however to stop it being a SPAM server, it needs some other kind of protection like a firewall.

Comment: So I need an open relay server?  Is there anywhere I can find one that wouldn't be blacklisted already?

Comment: You'd be unlikely to find a reliable one.  The best option is to create a new account somehwere and authenticate securely, or to set up your own server.

Comment: When you say authenticate securely, do you mean I would hard code the login credentials inside the program?  If so, how would I do that without them being exposed to a simple decompiler?

Comment: You may use windows authentication too.

Comment: A client application shouldn't send emails directly using your SMTP server.  if it needs to communicate with you then either allow the user to create an email in their own email program (not ideal as webmail is hard to support) or have an interface it can send you info with.

Answer (score 1):

GMail's SMTP server always requires authentication. You may need to setup your own server to send email without authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Configure an SMTP server into your local network (behind a firewall to avoid being a spam source) and use it directly. You can create one in IIS.

Comment: The problem is, other people will be using it outside of my network.

Comment: Then create a wcf service for your application that uses the smtp server internally, so you provide an external interface for your application only, but not an open smtp server.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to achieve this:

1) Use your local smtp server (e.g. one with IIS on Win2003/2008 server) and write messages to the local pickup queue). This is possible with minimal changes.

2) You need to resolve the target smtp server. For example when you want to send an email to somebody at msn.com, you'll need to get the MX record for msn.com, e.g. something like mx1.msn.com. You can then directly connect to this SMTP server and send your email to the (local) recipient. Note that there are no built-in ways to resolve the MX-host in .NET (in the sense there are no methods on the Dns class to accomplish this) - you need to do it "manually". Also most SMTP hosts will reject connections from home/residential IP addresses.